# Ionisation Energy vs First Ionisation Energy

Tags: physical-chemistry, ionization-energy

It was stated in a textbook that the first ionisation energy is

> the minimum energy needed to remove one mole of electrons from one mole of gaseous atoms in their ground state

Is there a difference between ionisation energy and *first* ionisation energy?

Comment: There is a first, second, third, fourth, … ionisation energy. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Jan not really. http://www.chemguide.co.uk/atoms/properties/moreies.html explains the successive ionisation energies with the equations, but ionisation energy isn't explained.

Comment: Well, ionisation energy is the general term and *first* ionisation energy specifies. As you would expect from language.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between "ionization energy" and "first ionization energy". Another definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy):

> The **ionization energy** (**IE**) is qualitatively defined as the amount of energy required to remove the most loosely bound electron, the valence electron, of an isolated gaseous atom to form a cation.

Here it's more clear that they are the same, since "the most loosely bound electron" is a *single* electron, and each successive ionization only removes a single electron at a time.

Additionally, if one were to remove all electrons from an atom, it would be explicitly stated as "complete ionization".

Comment: From both your and my definitions, I can see a difference. Can I confirm that the difference is that ionisation energy removes electrons from ONE atom, while the first, second third... ionisation energy removes electrons from ONE MOLE of atoms?

Comment: No. The definition of ionization energy is $\ce{X + \text{energy} -> X+ + e-}$, with nothing about atoms or moles. It's all about the _units_, which work out to be per mole. Units are consistent between all successive ionization energies.